# Mapping column values with index of List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below dataframe :

```
Df1

Col1
3     
5
6
7
9
```

and I have a below List

```
 Mapping_list=  ["Sales","Pre-Sales","Marketing", "Digital-Banking", "Payments", "telecom", "Core-Banking","Infra", "Cards", "Commercial-Banking" ]
```

I want to map column values with the index of the list like below:

```
Col1 Values
3    Digital-Banking
5    telecom
6    Core-Banking
7    Infra
9    Commercial-Banking
```

I could have done this if instead of list i need to map it with another dataframe index, but with list i am facing issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your list to [`series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) it, as `map` takes a `series`:

```
df['Values'] = df.Col1.map(pd.Series(Mapping_list))
```

Prints:

```
   Col1              Values
0     3     Digital-Banking
1     5             telecom
2     6        Core-Banking
3     7               Infra
4     9  Commercial-Banking
```